# ArcGIS API for Javascript - InfoTemplate on a polyline

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-api-wpf

I have a web map with a few points and a single polyline. I have infoTemplate(s) attached to the points and tried to replicate this to the polyline however, I can't get it to work. I looked on the ArcGIS API for JavaScript site and found an example against a polygon (hover) which is close but I need an example based on a polyline. Does anyone have a code sample that works for this request? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work to attach an infoTemplate to a polyline.

```
        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
        infoTemplate.setTitle("Your Title");
        infoTemplate.setContent("field1 label: w ${field1}<br/>" +
            "field2 label: ${field1}");

        polyline = new FeatureLayer("[Your Rest Endpoint URL]", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
            outFields: ["field1", "field2"]
        });

        map.addLayer(polyline);
```